# Display categories on BigCommerce store homepage

Tags: php, e-commerce, bigcommerce

I'm trying to get a custom homepage set up for a BigCommerce store. The store has a handful of products, in two categories. The customer wants the products from both categories displayed on the homepage of the store. Unfortunately BigCommerce only provides panels to display "New" or "Featured" products on the homepage.

Does anyone know how to create a custom panel to display the contents of a chosen category? I have the RSS links for the categories, I was hoping for something like this:

```
<div class="Block Moveable Panel" id="HomePageCategories">
<h2>Category One</h2>
   <div class="BlockContent">
    <display the first six items from URL source="rss-url-category-1">
   </div>
  <h2>Category Two</h2>
   <div class="BlockContent">
   <display the first six items from URL source="rss-url-category-2">
   </div>
</div>
```

Anyone have any suggestions or hints to how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I wound up just AJAXing in the contents of the respective content page's .ProductList ul's. Not ideal, but the best quick solution I found.

I created a new panel called HomePageCategories.HTML and pasted the AJAX function in, like so:

```
<div class="Block Moveable Panel" id="HomePageCategories">
<h2>Category Title One</h2>
   <div class="BlockContent" id="magaziner"></div>
  <h2>Category Title Two</h2>
   <div class="BlockContent" id="buecher"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var ajax_load = "path_to_loading_gif";

var loadMagaziner = "/magaziner/";    
$("#magaziner").html(ajax_load).load(loadMagaziner + " .ProductList");  

var loadBuecher = "/buecher/";
$("#buecher").html(ajax_load).load(loadBuecher + " .ProductList");
 </script>
```